# Change target from li to a class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have this code I've pieced together to accomplish drag and drop `div`s with drawn lines connecting them.

http://jsfiddle.net/GnY34/

However I don't want to have to use `li`s at all.. I rather have it attached directly to the `div`s (class `circle`).

I'm not sure what I need to change to make that happen?
Everything I try breaks it..

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You should make an jsFiddle that we can play with, would make it easier.

Comment: Good call, @sQVe ! http://jsfiddle.net/GnY34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update `"li"` to `"div"` in your `updateCanvas` function.

```
$("div", this).each(function() {
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/na8Qz/)

Comment: Thanks! What if I want it specific to div's with class "circle"?

Comment: @Reuben: You're already passing `$('.circle')` to the `updateCanvas` function, so it is already the case that it only targets the div's with the class "circle". `$('div', this)` is run within the context of a circle div, and relates to the `#a` and `#d` div's, that don't have that class.

Comment: @Reuben: well you must also update your markup, so that there are div's in your code, and not li's. See my demo.

Answer (score 1):

You just don't need the inner loop (each).

The source Included the lines that begins it's stroking from the middle of the element.
http://jsfiddle.net/GnY34/2/

Comment: remove the inner loop, so that you will also save a bit of browser's resources for different (canvas?) tasks. :)

Comment: I know this should probs be a new question, though how can the line come from the center instead if the left?